# Some exceptions are not being caught correctly in an embedded Mono runtime

Tags: c++, mono

We are using the embedded Mono runtime in a C++ application. Tested on Windows x86 and Mono 2.11

Scripts are executed by `mono_runtime_invoke`. When an unhanded exception occur in script-space it will be caught automatically :

```
MonoObject* exception = NULL;
MonoObject* returnObj = mono_runtime_invoke (m_method, m_objectInstance, NULL, &exception);
```

However, divide by zero exception is not caught and cause an exception in the C++ application !

Example :

```
int k = 0;
Console.WriteLine(1 / k);
```

Comment: It works here (both Linux and OSX): what architecture/operating system are you using?

Comment: The architecture is x86 on Windows 7. Mono built with Visual Studio.

Comment: Please file a bug in bugzilla.xamarin.com mentioning it's on windows, thanks!

Comment: It may be worth testing on Mono 2.10. Mono 2.11 is the unstable development branch of Mono.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem under 2.10.6 (stable).

Comment: Ok, I filled a bug report http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2607

Comment: Got the same with null reference exceptions (similar setup - x86 win2008server)...

Comment: Yes, I confirm, I can reproduce the bug with null reference exceptions

Comment: Have you checked it with 2.10.8? Works fine in my case:)

Comment: Well, they are not caught if I have VS debugger attached:)

Comment: I too can reproduce this with Mono 2.10.8 on Windows, I just noticed Bartosz's comment about not working
when in the Debugger, i'm going to try it outside the debugger as well.

Comment: @Eric I can reproduce the bug even in release mode and outside the debugger.